# Unfortunately stopped when button pressed in android navigation drawer

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

Hi I'm trying to make a small app using navigation drawer. here I've a button which is not worked.but my compiler doesn't give me any warning/error.

```
public class Fragment_sylhet extends  Fragment {

Button jflng;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater ,
                         ViewGroup container , Bundle saveInstanceState) {

    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sylhet, container,false);

    /*jflng = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.sylhet1);
    jflng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),Fragment_jaflong.class));
        }
    });*/
    jflng=(Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.sylhet1);
    jflng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),Fragment_jaflong.class);
            //startActivity(in);
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),Fragment_jaflong.class));
        }
    });

    return rootview;
}}
```

and my followinf fragment_shylet.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome to Sylhet Zone"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/sylht"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sylht">
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Jaflong"
    android:id="@+id/sylhet1"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_one"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my Fragment_jaflong.class is

```
public class Fragment_jaflong extends Fragment{
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jaflong, container, false);
return rootview;
}}
```

///// If i want to go any webpage via this button it works correctly but only when i call this class it disturbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't start a fragment with an intent. You need to start an activity that will start the fragment. Or you can open the fragment with a fragment transaction. Be sure to use the same view that the current Fragment is in.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

Fragment_jaflong frag = new Fragment_jaflong();
ft.replace(R.id.container, frag);
ft.commit();
```

[This is a good guide](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-fragment-transaction-fragmentmanager-and-backstack.html) to set up fragment transactions